# How do I change the render file path for AJAX call

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, controller, erb, ruby-on-rails-2

I'm running Rails `2.3.8` and I have a `respond_to` in my `Projects` controller `create` action.

```
def create
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to('/') }

    format.json :status => 200
  end
end
```

I have an AJAX call to this action. The Rails application then renders

```
projectdocs/create.erb
```

My question is, how can I change this file path within my action from `create.erb` to `create.erb.js`.

Answer (score 1):

I think your controller-name would be "projectdocs" an not "Project" if he renders "projectdocs/create.erb", but that's not the point.

You can explicit render a js-file using

```
 format.js { render :action => 'create' }
```

if this Format is requested.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on called format. If client wants js, add `format.js` and rails will try to render first of all `create.js.erb`